# RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox

Tags: linux, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Somebody...Who use Selenium with Firefox. Write:

- Which Firefox version you use
- Which geckodriver version you use
- And which selenium version you use

It's badly annoying! I have Firefox version 58.0.2, geckodriver 0.19.1, selenium 3.9.0, python 3.6.4 but it doesn't work ! Errors.

I installed Firefox without sudo apt-get (unzipped archive), cause repository haven't new version of Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is that selenium can't find Firefox because It's path isn't on your $PATH variable.

To solve the Issue, You've two options:

1. Install Firefox from a repository using the package manager
2. Specify the installed Firefox binary to selenium.
3. Add the Firefox binary to the Path variable.

For the second option:

To set the custom path to Firefox you need to use FirefoxBinary:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('/Firefox/Path')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

For the third option:

Add the following to your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/firefox"
```

Use 
`which firefox` or `whereis firefox` to get Firefox path.